# Как вытащить из файла нечётные строки?

Tags: python

Надо пропарсить файл с ip адресами. Из файла надо получить последнее слово каждой нечетной строчки (там ip). Делал так:

```
def main():

    infile = '/home/hooko/ping.txt'  
    tmp_ip = []
    f = open(infile)

    c_lin = CountNumOfRows(infile)    # ф-я получить кол-во строк в файле
    stl = f.readlines()

    for i in range(1,c_lin-1):  #со 2
        line = stl[i]       #текущая линия
        #x = not line % 2
        #if x == 0:         
        #  ip = tmp_ip[4]   
        #   
        tmp_ip = line.split()  #создать список слов разделенных ' '
        ip = tmp_ip[4] 
        print ip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Этим кодом получил такое:

192.168.0.1          
latency).
192.168.0.5
latency).
192.168.0.17
latency).
192.168.0.18
latency).

Не могу пропустить ненужные мне строки. Хотел так - проверяешь текущую строку на четность. Если нечетное, то "берем" ip, в противном случае - пропускаю.

В теле цикла пытался  организовать проверку на четность, но выдает такую ошибку - не пойму почему. 
Ошибка:

> `**Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "parser.py", line 33, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "parser.py", line 24, in main
>     x = line % 2`
>
> `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting**`

Если использовать этот блок ([показали такой пример](http://ideone.com/2WMaT))

```
for x in  range(0, 10):  
    if not x % 2 == 0:   
        print x
```

отдельно, то все в порядке.

Помогите плиз, разобраться с этой бедой. Если важно, то ОС - Ubuntu 10.10 (хотя думаю, что особо важно). В общем вопрос -  как прочитать последнее слово каждой не четной строки. А то я совсем запутался. ((

Comment: Хммм... странно, почему отступы "так плохо" запостились??? У меня в редакторе все путем, ошибок по части отступов нет.

Comment: @hooko Нужно добавить в редакторе перед вставкой уровень идентации (четыре пробела или табуляцию) перед каждой строкой, тогда код отформатируется правильно.

Comment: ответ на вопрос в заголовке: [`sed 'n;d'`](https://askubuntu.com/q/998685/3712) (это полная команда)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изощрения излишни, запустите цикл с шагом 2 и будет вам счастье.
Пример:

```
for x in xrange(1, c_lin - 1, 2):
    print x
```

Третий параметр задает шаг [step]. Тогда отбрасываете все проверки, и работает =)
Ваш код будет иметь следующий вид:

```
for i in range(1, c_lin - 1, 2):
    line = stl[i]
    tmp_ip = line.split()
    ip = tmp_ip[4] 
    print ip
```

И лучше использовать xrange вместо range, range - создает список, а Вам в данном случае это не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить последнюю колонку, отделённую пробелом, из каждой нечётной строчки, считая с нуля, в заданном файле на Питоне:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    odd_lines = file.readlines()[1::2]
ips = [line.rstrip().rpartition(' ')[2] for line in odd_lines]
```

Чтобы понять как это работает, можно в REPL поиграться:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range(5)[1::2]
[1, 3]
>>> 'a b c'.rpartition(' ')[2]
'c'
```

---

Если файл может быть большой, то [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) позволяет прочитать нечётные строчки не загружая весь файл в память:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename) as file:
    for odd_line in islice(file, 1, None, 2):
        print(odd_line.rstrip().rpartition(' ')[2]) # print ip (last column)
```

`islice()` выполняет роль `[1::2]` здесь:

```
>>> list(islice(range(5), 1, None, 2))
[1, 3]
```

---

Чтобы вытащить все ip-адреса в формате x.x.x.x из файла:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    ips = re.findall(r'\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+', file.read())
```

Если файл большой, то чтобы не загружать весь файл как строку, можно [`mmap` использовать, чтобы создать функцию `generate_tokens()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024735/4279):

```
for m in generate_tokens(filename, br'\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+'):
    print(m.group().decode()) # print ip
```