# Каким образом удалить строчки выборочно?

Tags: python

Есть некий файл, состоящий из строк. Нужно удалить выборочно строки, начинающиеся с определенного набора символов при помощи python. Как это сделать?

Вот пример

```
ATOM 14
ATOM 15
ANISOU 15
ATOM 16
ANISOU 16
```

нужно удалить все, что начинается с ANISOU

Comment: У вас есть идеи и предложения того, как это сделать не лучше, а хоть как-нибудь? Какие-то конкретные проблемы?

Comment: Приношу свои извинения за то, что незаслуженно закрыл этот вопрос *04.03.2017*. Надеюсь, больше не повторю таких ошибок.

Answer (score 7):

> Как удалить каждую вторую строку из файла на python?

[Используя `fileinput`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446842/23044), чтобы прозрачно создать временный файл, чтобы по месту изменения выполнить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
import os

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file, start=1):
        if i & 1: # odd 
            print(line, end='') # keep line (stdout is redirected to the file)
os.unlink(filename + '.bak') # remove the backup on success
```

Этот for-цикл можно также записать, [используя `itertools.islice`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499119/23044):

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

sys.stdout.writelines(islice(file, 0, None, 2))  # keep lines[::2]
```

Если реализация `.writelines()` не пишет строки по мере поступления, а загружает их всех в память, то можно использовать явный for-цикл, чтобы по одной строке писать, не загружая весь файл в память.

Для небольшого файла полный код может использовать `.readlines()`, чтобы получить список строк (загрузить файл в память) и целиком перезаписать этот файл, рискуя потерять данные если ошибка возникнет:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[::2] # lines to keep
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Для небольшого файла, заданного с командной строки или стандартного ввода (stdin), пренебрегая возможными ошибками, [можно кратко записать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612251/23044):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput
from itertools import islice

print("".join(islice(fileinput.input(), 0, None, 2)), end='')
```

это полный скрипт. Использование:

```
$ every-other-line file1 file2 >output_file
```

В более общем случае, чтобы удалить строки по месту из файла, не создавая временный файл и не загружая всё содержимое в память, [`seek()/tell()` работают](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40821253/4279), но вероятно менее эффективное решение создают:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(filename, 'r+') as file:
    write_offset = file.tell() # where to write next
    for line in islice(iter(file.readline, ''), 0, None, 2):  # keep lines[::2]
        read_offset = file.tell() # where to read next
        file.seek(write_offset)
        file.write(line)
        write_offset = file.tell()
        file.seek(read_offset)
    file.truncate(write_offset)
```

Этот более сложный вариант работает и для файлов, которые как в оперативную память не помещаются так и для которых нет места, чтобы копию на диске создать.

> нужно удалить все, что начинается с ANISOU

Можно адаптировать приведённые выше примеры кода:

```
import fileinput
import os

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        if not line.startswith('ANISOU'): 
            print(line, end='') # keep line (stdout is redirected to the file)
os.unlink(filename + '.bak') # remove the backup on success
```

Можно [самостоятельно временный файл создать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593167/23044) (к примеру, если в текущей директории не достаточно места для копии файла, можно явно другую директорию указать (на другом диске) и использовать [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), если необходимо):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

path = Path(filename)
with path.open() as file, \
     NamedTemporaryFile('w', dir=str(path.parent), delete=False) as output_file: 
     for line in file:
         if not line.startswith('ANISOU'): 
             print(line, end='', file=output_file)
Path(output_file.name).replace(path)
```

Загрузив строки в память:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = [line for line in file if not line.startswith('ANISOU')]
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Легко адаптировать к другим условиям, определив `keep_line()` предикат, к примеру:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    lines = list(filter(keep_line, file))
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

где в данном случае:

```
def keep_line(line):
    return not line.startswith('ANISOU')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
f=open("./файл.txt","r") # открытие фала на чтение
f2=open("./файл2.txt","w") # открытие файла на запись результата
stroka=" " # Создаем не пустую строку, будет использоваться для построчного чтения файла
while stroka!="" : # Запускам цикл в котором будет построчно считываться файл, в конце файла параметр stroka станет равен пустой строке и цикл завершится
    stroka=f.readline() # Построчное чтение файла
    if stroka[:6]!="ANISOU": f2.write(stroka) # Если строка не начинается с ANISOU то строка запишется в файл результата

f.close # закрытие файла
f2.close # закрытие файла
```

Comment: [ться/тся](http://img1.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/d/1/131/99/131099949_Russkiy_yazuyk_v_kotah48.jpg) :)

Comment: В файле не должно быть пустых строк?

Comment: @vp_arth: даже пустая строка имеет `"\n"` в ней. `stroka == ""` означает EOF. Нужно сказать код в ответе, не является идиоматическим. Этот алгоритм, можно записать как: `for line in file: if not line.startswith('ANISOU'): output_file.write(line)`