# Замена только в определённых линиях файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

### 1. Кратко

Имеется файл. В нём нужно произвести замены только на определённых линиях. Некоторые линии необходимо игнорировать.

Желательно сделать это без дублирующегося кода (для кода вроде п. 3.1 данного вопроса).

---

### 2. Минимальный пример

- `Kira.txt`:

```text
Sasha
Sasha*-U Can't Touch This
Sasha Goddess!
```

- `main.py`

```python
import re

with open("Kira.txt", "r+") as kira_file:
    file_as_string = kira_file.read()
    kira_file.seek(0)
    kira_file.write(re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', file_as_string, flags=re.M))
    kira_file.truncate()
```

- Вывод (перезаписанный `main.py`):

```text
Kira
Kira*-U Can't Touch This
Kira Goddess!
```

А нужно, чтобы любая строка, содержащая `Touch` (в примере — вторая), не была затронута заменами. `Touch` — условная метка, показывающая, что модулю ничего не следует делать с данной линией. То есть, чтобы файл перезаписался так:

```text
Kira
Sasha*-U Can't Touch This
Kira Goddess!
```

---

### 3. Попытки самостоятельно справиться с заданием

Пробовал также использовать метод `writelines` вместо `write` или модуль `itertools` — безуспешно.

#### 3.1. Поиск и замена на линии

- [**Онлайн-демонстрация на Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-Replaceinsomestrings-1)

Попробую выполнить то же самое, что и в п.2, но чтобы поиск/замена велась для определённой линии.

```python
"""Минимальный пример."""
import re


def initial_function():
    """Получаю список строк, в которых будет вестись поиск или замена.

    В реальном модуле, чтобы получить список, выполняю много действий:
    (https://www.pastery.net/npjxzx/).
    В минимальном же примере в списке убираются строки, содержащие «Touch».
    Строки, не вошедшие в список, это строки-исключения, в них поиск и замена
    вестись не должны.
    """
    with open("Kira.txt", "r+") as kira_file:
        file_as_list = kira_file.readlines()
        final_list = [_ for _ in file_as_list if 'Touch' not in _]
        yield kira_file, final_list


def find_function():
    """Функция-пример.

    Список, полученный в прошлой функции,
    нужен, чтобы по его пунктам выполнить поиск на определённое вхождение.
    Вставил эту функцию в пример, потому что хотелось бы рабочий код, где не пришлось бы
    дублировать действия для получения списка неисключённых строк
    для этой функции и в replace_function().
    """
    for kira_file, final_list in initial_function():
        for line in final_list:
            if "Goddess" in line:
                print(f"{line} contain Goddess")
            else:
                print(f"{line} not contain Goddess")


def replace_function():
    """В этой функции пытаюсь выполнить замену."""
    for kira_file, final_list in initial_function():
        for line in final_list:
            kira_file.seek(0)
            kira_file.write(re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', line, flags=re.M))
            kira_file.truncate()


# find_function()
replace_function()
```

- Вывод (перезаписанный `main.py`):

```text
Kira Goddess!
```

Всё удалилось кроме последней заменённой строки.

#### 3.2. tell()

Пробовал не использовать `seek(0)` или [**использовать `tell()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15594928/5951529)

- [**Онлайн-демонстрация на Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-Replaceinsomestrings-2):

```python
def replace_function():
    """В этой функции пытаюсь выполнить замену."""
    for kira_file, final_list in initial_function():
        for line in final_list:
            # kira_file.seek(0)
            kira_file.write(re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', line, flags=re.M))
            kira_file.truncate()
```

- или:

```python
def replace_function():
    """В этой функции пытаюсь выполнить замену."""
    for kira_file, final_list in initial_function():
        for line in final_list:
            last_pos = kira_file.tell()
            kira_file.seek(last_pos)
            kira_file.write(re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', line, flags=re.M))
            kira_file.truncate()
```

- Вывод (перезаписанный `main.py`):

```text
Sasha
Sasha*-U Can't Touch This
Sasha Goddess!Kira
Kira Goddess!
```

---

### 4. Пояснения

1. Линии, где требуется и нет проводить замены, могут быть расположены в любом месте файла. Код, подобный [**этому**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4719562/5951529), приспособить к решению данной задачи, у меня не вышло.
2. Нужно перезаписать исходный файл, а не вывести конечный результат в новый файл. Использование временных файлов, если это необходимо, конечно, не возбраняется.
3. Линии-исключения после проведения операции замены должны оставаться в файле. В них не требуется ничего изменять, но удалять нельзя. Вариант: записать заменённые линии в другой файл → перезаписать исходный файл, у меня не проходил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если так принципиально работать без временного файла, переоткрывайте этот

```
import re

def initial_function(file_name: str) -> list:
    """Получаю список строк, в которых будет вестись поиск или замена.
    В реальном модуле, чтобы получить список, выполняю много действий:
    В минимальном же примере в списке убираются строки, содержащие «Touch».
    """
    with open(file_name, 'r') as kira_file:
        text = kira_file.readlines()
    return text # просто возвращаем нефильтрованный список, полученный за много действий

def find_function(line:str) -> bool:
    """по его пунктам выполнить поиск на определённое вхождение. """
    return 'Touch' not in line


def replace_function(line:str) -> str:
    return re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', line, flags=re.M)


def process_file(file_name):
    text = initial_function(file_name)
    with open(file_name, "w") as kira_file:
        for line in text:
            if find_function(line):
                line = replace_function(line)
            kira_file.write(line)

process_file("Kira.txt")
```

UPD: Вынес функционал получения, фильтра и замены в функции

Comment: 2 проблемы возникают. // **1.** [**Этот код**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-LecronReplaceExample-1) будет работать, как нужно. Но в `find_function()` нужно будет передать одну переменную, в `replace_function()` — линтеры будут репортировать об unused variable `file_as_list` на 29 строке кода.

Comment: // **2.** 1 файл, как понял, придётся открывать дважды в разных режимах? Если попробовать открыть 1 раз в режиме `r+`, в итоге новое содержимое добавится в конец файла, а не перезапишет его, [**пример**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-LecronReplaceExample-2). Плюс те же unused variables. // Спасибо.

Comment: Временные файлы, конечно, не возбраняются, если работать с ними — это правильный путь. Поправил вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных Изменил точно под условия вопроса. Все работает.

Comment: Ув-мый Lecron, это всё я понял и это есть [**в моём примере**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-LecronReplaceExample-1). Но тогда возникают другие проблемы, описанные в комментариях. `В вашем коде ничего не понял.` — что именно, могли бы пояснить, чтобы я, в свою очередь, мог объяснить? Спасибо.

Comment: `if 'Touch' not in line` вместе с `else` не стоит использовать

Comment: @Саша Черных Я не понял общей логики. Зачем всюду таскать с собой файл? Есть сложные обработки? оформляйте их в чистые функции, не тянущие за собой кучу контекста. Закрывая файл при выходе из функции.

Comment: Для `find_function()` нужна только переменная `final_list`, для `replace_function` — ещё и переменная `kira_file`. Вопрос в том, как передать переменные. Вижу 3 варианта: **1.** Написать, как [**здесь**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-LecronReplaceExample-1), но тогда получится неиспользованная переменная (см. прошлые комментарии), **2.** Использовать `global`, что никогда не рекомендуется. **3.** Писать дублирующийся код. Т. е. в `replace_function` получать переменные так же, как и в `initial_function()`. // Но, видимо, есть какой-то другой, правильный вариант.

Comment: `оформляйте их в чистые функции, не тянущие за собой кучу контекста.` — могли бы на примере показать? Что-то вроде [**этого**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraSO-LecronReplaceExample-3) не работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных Сделал

Answer (score 1):

[Каким образом удалить строчки выборочно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633622) - взято отсюда

```
from itertools import islice

with open('Kira.txt', 'r+') as file:
    write_offset = file.tell() # where to write next
    for line in islice(iter(file.readline, ''), 0, None):
        read_offset = file.tell() # where to read next
        file.seek(write_offset)
        if 'Touch' in line:
            ...
        write_offset = file.tell()
        file.seek(read_offset)
    file.truncate(write_offset)
```

если упростить ответ Lecron

держать в памяти не более 1 линии файла:

```
def process_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name + '.tmp', "w") as file_w, open(file_name, 'r') as file_r:
        for line in file_r:
            if 'Touch' not in line:
                line = re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', line, flags=re.M)
            file_w.write(line)
    shutil.move(file_name + '.tmp', file_name)
```

держать в памяти весь файл:

```
def process_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file_r:
        text = list(file_r)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file_w:
        for line in text:
            if 'Touch' not in line:
                line = re.sub(r'Sasha', r'Kira', line, flags=re.M)
            file_w.write(line)
```

Comment: А если замена делает строку длиннее, то что будет?

Comment: будет плохо :) ну по ссылке способы прочитать записать описаны. Остальное уже детали. Конечно текстовый файл не надо через seek. Или построчно читать или сразу в буфер из итератора as file.

Comment: Или вычислить размер максимальной замены и читать на нужное количество строк на опережение.